# C code in visual studio 2015 errors

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

guys! I have some problems with using Visual studio 2015 and using this C code. I have to use C in for university so I do not have choice. I get a lot of errors that I have no idea what they mean. I fixed some of them, but others are just mindbogglingly complex to me. Here is the code and an IMGUR ling to an image with all my errors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa84Y.png

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct Product {
    int kod;
    char ime[20], mqrka[20];
    float cena, kol;
};

char *fime[30];
FILE *fp;
Product pr;

void createfile() {
    fp = fopen_s(*fime, "wb");
    fclose(fp);
    printf_s("Файлът е създаден!\n");
}

void readProduct(Product *p) {
    printf_s("Данни за нов продукт:\n");
    printf_s("Код: "); scanf_s("%d", &p->kod); getchar();
    printf_s("Име: "); gets_s(p->ime);
    printf_s("Мярка: "); gets_s(p->mqrka);
    printf_s("Единична цена: "); scanf_s("%f", &p->cena);
    printf_s("Количество: "); scanf_s("%f", &p->kol);
    getchar();

}

void addData() {
    fp = fopen_s(*fime, "a+b");
    char c;
    do {
        readProduct(&pr);
        fwrite(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
        printf_s("Още продукти? (y/n) : ");
        c = getchar(); getchar();
    } while (c == 'y');
    fclose(fp);
}

void writeProducts() {
    fp = fopen_s(*fime, "rb");
    printf_s("Продукти във файла:\n");
    fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        printf_s("%d %s с количество:%f\n", pr.kod, pr.ime, pr.kol);
        fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void changeProduct() {
    fp = fopen_s(*fime, "r+b");
    int k;
    printf_s("Задай код на продукт: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        if (pr.kod == k) {
            float dk;
            printf_s("Въведи допълнително количество: ");
            scanf_s("%f", &dk);
            pr.kol += dk;
            fseek(fp, -(long) sizeof(pr), SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
            printf_s("Добавено е количество към продукт: %s \n", pr.ime);
            break;
        }
        fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void calculateMoney() {
    fp = fopen_s(*fime, "rb");
    float suma = 0.0;
    fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        suma = pr.kol*pr.cena;
        fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf_s("Налична стока в пари: %.2f\n", suma);
}

void writeData() {
    char imqrka[20];
    fp = fopen_s(*fime, "rb");
    fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    getchar();
    printf_s("Въведи зададена мярка:");
    gets_s(imqrka);
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        if (strcmp(imqrka, pr.mqrka) == 0 && pr.kol>0) {
            printf_s("%d %s с количество:%f\n", pr.kod, pr.ime, pr.kol);
        }
        fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void writeTextFile() {
    FILE *txt;
    txt = fopen_s("products.txt", "wt");
    fp = fopen_s(*fime, "rb");
    fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fprintf(txt, "%d %s с количество:.2%f и цена:%.2f\n", pr.kod, pr.ime, pr.kol, pr.cena);
        fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(txt);
    printf_s("Продуктите се записаха в текстовия файл.\n");
}

void deleteData() {
    FILE *temp = fopen_s("temp", "rb");
    int k;
    printf_s("Въведи код:");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    fp = fopen_s(fime, "rb");
    fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        if (pr.kod != k)
            fwrite(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, temp);
        else
            printf_s("продукът е изтрит: \n");
        fread(&pr, sizeof(pr), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(fime);
    rename("temp", fime);
}
void main() {
    system("chcp 1251");
    printf_s("Име на файл: ");
    gets_s(fime);
    int otg;
    do {
        printf_s("\nМеню\n");
        printf_s("0 - Изход\n");
        printf_s("1 - Създаване на празен файл.\n");
        printf_s("2 - Добавяне към файла.\n");
        printf_s("3 - Промяна на количество по зададен код.\n");
        printf_s("4 - Изчисляване на налична стока в парично изражение.\n");
        printf_s("5 - Извеждане всички продукти със зададена мярка и количество > 0.\n");
        printf_s("6 - Извеждане всички продукти от файла.\n");
        printf_s("7 - Извеждане всички продукти в текстов файл.\n");
        printf_s("8 - Изтриване на продукт от файла по зададен код.\n");
        printf_s("Избери: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &otg);
        switch (otg) {
        case 1: createfile(); break;
        case 2: addData(); break;
        case 3: changeProduct(); break;
        case 4: calculateMoney(); break;
        case 5: writeData(); break;
        case 6: writeProducts(); break;
        case 7: writeTextFile(); break;
        case 8: deleteData(); break;
        }
    } while (otg != 0);
}
```

Comment: Fix the simplest first: too few arguments for function call, by reading the man page for the function called, and correcting it. After that some of the other errors might go away, as in those cases the supplied arguments could not be properly matched to the arguments required.

Comment: This code written in visual studio 2006 by my professor, so I think there are no actual errors just some minor differences for 2015 that I'm too dumb to understand.

Comment: The declaration of `fime` is incorrect.

Comment: If I correctly recall, MSVC 2006 did not have those "safer" functions. Just sticking a `_s` suffix does not do the job - more arguments are usually required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is that **you are using `fopen_s` function the wrong way.**

according to **[manpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx)** *(click to know more)* of `fopen_s()`, three arguments are to be passed:

```
errno_t fopen_s(   
   FILE** pFile,  
   const char *filename,  
   const char *mode   
);
```

so in your code, the following is wrong as you are sending too few (only two)* arguments

```
txt = fopen_s("products.txt", "wt");
```

instead, you must do:

```
fopen_s(&txt, "products.txt", "wt");
```

and don't assign the return value of `fopen_s` which is of the type `errno_t` to `txt` which is of the type `FILE*`.